# Gorilla Websocket - Read error: repeated read on failed websocket connection

Tags: go, websocket, server, gorilla

Using the gorilla websocket api for go, how do i know if a client is still connected?

What Im trying with now is:

```
func Listen(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    connTimeout := 3
    timeLastSent := time.Now().Second()

    for ((timeLastSent + connTimeout) % 60) != time.Now().Second() {

        msg := Message{}
        err := ws.ReadJSON(&msg)

        if err == websocket.ErrCloseSent {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            continue
        }

        //Message recived
        EventMessage <- msg

        timeLastSent = time.Now().Second()
    }
  //Connection timed out.
    return
}
```

But this results in the error `repeated read on failed websocket connection`.

Ive been looking into using `ws.SetReadDeadline(t)`, but Ive no idea of either how to use it nor if its even the thing Im looking for.

How should i go about this?

Comment: Have you checked the examples in the Github repo?

Comment: @JohnSmith [This one](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/server.go)?

Comment: Nope, [this one](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/filewatch/main.go).

Comment: @JohnSmith I'm not sure how that would help :/ could you explain?

Comment: It shows how to handle ping/pong requests. Basically you don't really need to do anything other than handling the deadlines as it is in the example. Once there is no response from the client within the specified timeframe, you can just return (close the connection on the server).

Comment: Alright, thanks. Think i got it now

Answer (score 3):

When the websocket connection fails with an error other than `websocket.ErrCloseSent`, the program spins in a tight loop until the timeout.

To help applications detect this programming error, the websocket package panics when read is called 1000 times on a failed connection ([view code here](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/e8629af678b7fe13f35dff5e197de93b4148a909/conn.go#L996-L1002)).

To fix the problem, break out of the loop on all errors:

```
    err := ws.ReadJSON(&msg)
    if err != nil {
        // optional: log the error
        break
    }
```

Use [the connection's read deadline](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.SetReadDeadline) to handle timeouts.